# Search a MySQL DB field for multiple text

Tags: php, mysql, search

I currently have the following that will search a field within my db for a mention of one word, but would like to know if it is possible that if a customer enter two words, rather than   only output anything matching that particular format, it actually splits the words up and returns the result for both words not an exact match:

Currently have

```
   WHERE title LIKE '%SEARCH TEXT HERE%'..
```

so if a user currently enter 'FISH' or 'FISH FOOD' then it will return only the columns that have that text within in it as it is.

What i would like to happen is if they entered more than one word then it actually splits that up and then searches and returns the results for all the separate words.

So 'FISH FOOD' would return all rows with the word fish or food with in  and not just anything that matched 'FISH FOOD'

Using PHP and MySQL

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your search string into parts (explode(" ", $string)).
Then add for each part a condition title LIKE "%$part%' OR title LIKE "%$part%' OR ...

Comment: thansk for the reply that was my thinking which experimenting now, also @Greg P thanks will let you now th eout come

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to break up the string of keywords and do the query like this:

```
WHERE title LIKE '%SEARCH%' OR title LIKE '%TEXT%' OR title LIKE '%HERE%'..
```

Though more complex, if you're up to the learning curve of Full Text, I would agree with bpgergo's answer.  It has many advantages to simple "LIKE" queries.  Consider this:

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE title like '%BIO%'
```

This will return anything with "BIOLOGY", "BIOgraphy", etc.  Full Text understands word boundaries so these "challenges" are addresses.  Also, you can use the matching Relevance, and use that when sorting your results.

It also considers "stop" words, so if the user put in "Food for my fish", it would still only match for "Food" and "Fish" because "for" and "my" are common words that would be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Greg P, @ErikFWinter and @bpgergo  for the replies i was looking into this method at the time, best add my answer for future ref:

```
  $search = explode(' ', $title);
    $searchResults = 'LIKE ';
    foreach ($search as $id => $word) {
        $searchResults .= "'%" . $word . "%'";
        $searchResults .= " OR title LIKE ";
    }
    $searchResults = rtrim($searchResults," OR title LIKE ");

    return $this->db->select("SELECT videoid, title, formatloc FROM db_vList WHERE title {$searchResults} order by title asc");
```

There might be an easier why but learning is learning much appreciated.

Si

Answer (score 0):

What you need sir is the FULLTEXT index of MySQL.

Here is a detailed example that does just what you're looking for.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

**EDIT** this is a pure SQL solution.

for the convenience of SO, I have copied the relevant SQL here:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
d INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(200),
body TEXT,
FULLTEXT (title,body)
ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO articles (title,body) VALUES
('MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...'),
('How To Use MySQL Well','After you went through a ...'),
('Optimizing MySQL','In this tutorial we will show ...'),
('1001 MySQL Tricks','1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...'),
('MySQL vs. YourSQL','In the following database comparison ...'),
('MySQL Security','When configured properly, MySQL ...');

SELECT id, body, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
('Security implications of running MySQL as root') AS score
FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
('Security implications of running MySQL as root');
```